# simplification of multiplying rational expressions

Tags: factoring

I cant' get the right answer to simplifying this expression:

$$\frac{x^2+x-6}{x} \cdot \frac{x^2-3x}{x^2-9}$$

The answer I have is ${x - 2}.$

I can simplify it to

$$\frac{x^2-6}{x} \cdot \frac{x(x-3)}{(x-3)(x+3)}$$

And from there to

$$(x - 6) \cdot \frac{x}{x+3}$$

I'm not sure if I've taken a wrong turn or how ${x - 2}$ was obtained from here.

Comment: $$\frac{x^2+x-6}{x}=\frac{(x+3)(x-2)}{x}$$

$$\frac{x^2+x-6}{x}*\frac{x^2}{x^2-9}=\frac{(x+3)(x-2)}{x}*\frac{x}{x+3}=x-2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably just misread:
$$
\frac{(x-2)(x+3)}{x}\frac{x(x-3)}{(x-3)(x+3)} = \frac{x-2}{x}\frac{x(x-3)}{(x-3)}=x-2
$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

In the first line

$$x^2+x-6=(x+3)(x-2)$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to help and give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

You must have misread x<sup>2</sup> +x - 6 as x<sup>2</sup>  - 6 

we can simplify this to (x+3)(x-2)